# preg_replace segmentation fault

Tags: php, regex

Not trying to parse HTML, but trying to remove from between tags of RSS (XML). Is that sinister too? Used this:

```
preg_replace('/\<\/description\>(?:.|\n)*\<content:encoded\>/', '</description><content:encoded>', $content);
```

and got (in apache)

```
AH00052: child pid 24919 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

even did

```
pcre.recursion_limit = 1000
```

But then the output came back blank.

There are multiple items in the RSS and each item has (of many other tags) `<description></description>` followed by `<content:encoded>`. But once a while web pages creep in between the `</description>` and `<content:encoded>`. If regex is not the way what is better alternative?

Comment: Can you try this regex: [`\<\/description\>[\s\S]*?\<content:encoded\>`](https://regex101.com/r/YmxzIz/2)

Comment: A simple fix - `'~</description>.*?<content:encoded>~s'`. A bit more advanced - `'~</description>[^<]*(?:<(?!content:encoded>)[^<]*)*<content:encoded>~'`. It seems you may just use string manipulations if you treat the XML as plain text.